# 403s appearing in WMT but FETCH as GOOGLE returning same URLs as 200

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-403

HI there over the last few days WMT has been showing me 403 errors for a series of URLS. However when i FETCH them they come up as 200 OK and when i look in google using keywords they appear in the index. Everything seems fine except for the errors. Is there any reason for this? Is there anywhere i should check for the cause of this. Its a wordpress site @ www.mutantspace.com. Here are a sample of URLs:

```
http://www.mutantspace.com/daniel-palacios-waves-art-installation/
http://www.mutantspace.com/thilde-jensen-the-canaries-photographs/
```

thanks
Moray

Comment: Mark them as fixed and see if they return.  
For future reference, this type off question is much better of being asked on the webmasters version http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-webmaster-tools

Comment: thanks Michael ill put the question over there